# Is there a `watch` command native to Darwin/OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script, darwin

I have a script that I'm trying to port from Linux to Darwin/OS X. The Linux version currently depends on the `watch` command, which doesn't appear to be installed on Darwin/OS X by default. What's the native alternative?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574089/osx-bash-watch-command/9574123

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no native alternative. You must acquire `watch` from using Homebrew (`brew install watch`) or MacPorts (`port install watch`) if you require an actual executable.

You can however, emulate the function of `watch`. That can be accomplished in a standard bash while loop ([from Stack Overflow by Daniel Pittman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574123/5256246)):

> You can emulate the basic functionality with the shell loop:
>
> ```
> while :; do clear; your_command; sleep 2; done
> ```
>
> That will loop forever, clear the screen, run your command, and wait two seconds - the basic watch your_command implementation.
>
> You can take this a step further and create a watch.sh script that can
>   accept your_command and sleep_duration as parameters:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # usage: watch.sh <your_command> <sleep_duration>
>
> while :;
>   do
>   clear
>   date
>   $1
>   sleep
>   $2
> done
> ```

[That, and other options, are available on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574089/osx-bash-watch-command)